# What are my binding options for a self hosted cross domain WCF service with remote thick clients?

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to build a WCF self hosted service (eventually in a windows service) that will receive binary and text base messages from remote thick clients that have no accounts on my hosted machine.  I'm trying to figure out both my binding options and security options, and in reading the patterns and practices guides, my head has completely spun around at least once.

The clients would be authenticated against a custom SQL based method, so I'd like to be able to pass that info in the initial login request and then set an authorization token of some kind.  (This part of the problem is probably outside the scope of the question, but I included it in case it *might* make a difference.)

Any thoughts at all would be very helpfull.

Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice of binding and security option depends on the usage of your WCF service. Is it just for your rich client or are you planning to expose it to the world as API? If it's just for your rich app, does it run on LAN or over untrusted, unreliable Internet?

With WCF you can configure the service to expose multiple endpoints with different bindings, for example [both SOAP and REST](http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-restful-pox-json-and-soap-coexist.html). In general, I'd start with something stateless and lightweight like basicHttpBinding and webHttpBinding, passing user and password on every request. Once you have that up and running you can optimize cache authentication,   provide binary endpoint etc.. only if it actually helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have just one binding. Having said that if it's self hosted you're "on your own" here. I've never looked at what's involved.